# C++11: `error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token in code` for line sweep to find closest pair

Tags: c++, c++11

This is an attempted O(NlogN) solution to the [closest pair problem](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&Itemid=99999999&page=show_problem&category=&problem=1186&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+17697249), written in C++11. I used [std::complex for geometry](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22175). The comparators may be confusing, to the explain: `cmp` initially sorts the points by x and then y, and `compare_y` sorts the points in the [bounding box](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs251/ClosestPair/ClosestPairPS.html) by y value.

The following are the errors I get, followed by my code.

```
cp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cp.cpp:49:95: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
                 for (set<point>::iterator it = s.lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), t1, compare_y); it < s.upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), t2, compare_y); ++it) {
                                                                                               ^
cp.cpp:49:150: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
                 for (set<point>::iterator it = s.lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), t1, compare_y); it < s.upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), t2, compare_y); ++it) {
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const double EPS = 1e-9;

// define x, y as real(), imag()
typedef complex<double> point;
#define x real()
#define y imag()

bool cmp(point a, point b) {
    if (a.x < b.x) return true;
    if (a.x - b.x < EPS && a.y < b.y) return true;
    return false;
}

struct compare_y {
    bool operator() (const point& lhs, const point& rhs) const{
        if (lhs.y < rhs.y) return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    int n;
    while (scanf("%d", &n) && n != 0) {

        vector<point> coord;
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            double xi, yi;
            scanf("%lf%lf", &xi, &yi);
            point t(xi, yi);
            coord.push_back(t);
        }
        sort(coord.begin(), coord.end(), cmp);

        double h = 10000000;
        set<point, compare_y> s;
        s.insert(coord[0]);
        for (int i=1; i<n; ++i) {

            for (auto pt:s) {
                if (abs(pt-coord[i])+EPS > h) { // bound by x
                    s.erase(pt);
                }
            }
            point t1 = coord[i]; t1.imag(t1.y - h);
            point t2 = coord[i]; t2.imag(t2.y + h);
            for (set<point>::iterator it = s.lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), t1, compare_y); it < s.upper_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), t2, compare_y); ++it) {
                h = min(h, abs(*it-coord[i]));
            }


            s.insert(coord[i]);
        }
        if (h + EPS >= 10000)
            printf("INFINITY\n");
        else
            printf("%.4lf\n", h);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why was there a downvote? Is my question inappropriate for this site?

Comment: The error is because you are trying to pass `compare_y` where a function argument is expected, but `compare_y` is the name of a type, not an object. There are other problems that you'll need to fix too though, as Barry explains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't use [`<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/2069064).

Second of all, you are confusing the member function [`std::set::lower_bound()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) with the algorithm [`std::lower_bound()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) - they take different arguments. The member function just takes a single argument (the other three are implied - the range of the set and the comparator. Though even for `std::lower_bound()`, you're providing the comparator incorrectly as that argument needs to be an object and you're simply providing a typename).

Thirdly, `s` is a `std::set<point, compare_y>` so those member functions return a `std::set<point, compare_y>::iterator` and not a `std::set<point>::iterator`.

Fourthly, `std::set<point, compare_y>::iterator` is not random-access and thus does not have `operator<` defined. You need to use `!=`.

The correct line would be:

```
for (std::set<point, compare_y>::iterator it = s.lower_bound(t1); it != s.upper_bound(t2); ++it) {
```

or just :

```
for (auto it = s.lower_bound(t1); it != s.upper_bound(t2); ++it) {
```

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, I'll accept when I'm allowed to in 5 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: I realize this is out of the bounds of the question, but if you could give one more tip: I got a time limit exceeded for this code (and I didn't when I just brute forced with line sweep (no set)). Do you see anything that would make this code not run in time? I'm not going to make you answer this for the correct answer; I'll accept it anyway. Just wondering if you could give a bonus.